# Find two keywords if they are between 0 and 3 words apart

Tags: r, regex

I want to identify strings which feature two keywords that have between 0 and 3 words between them. What I have works in most cases:

```r
strings <- c(
  "Today is my birthday",
  "Today is not yet my birthday",
  "Today birthday",
  "Today maybe?",
  "Today: birthday"
)


grepl("Today(\\s\\w+){0,3}\\sbirthday", strings, ignore.case = TRUE)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

My issue is with the string `"Today: birthday"`. The problem is that a word is defined as `(\\s\\w+)` leaving no option for the sentence to contain any punctuation. How can I better define the regex for word so that punctuation is not excluded (best would be to ignore it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
> grepl("Today(\\W+\\w+){0,3}\\W+birthday", strings, ignore.case = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Also, consider using word boundaries, non-capturing groups, and the more stable PCRE regex engine:

```r
grepl("\\bToday(?:\\W+\\w+){0,3}\\W+birthday\\b", strings, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

The `(?:\W+\w+){0,3}\W+` part matches zero to three occurrences of one or more non-word chars (`\W+`) and then one or more word chars (`\w+`) and then one or more non-word chars.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Seems like a super obvious solution in hindsight :D